# Action generated by geodesic flow is hamiltonian

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

I'm trying to understand why a certain action of a Lie Group is hamiltonian.

Let $(M,g)$ be a geodesically complete Riemannian manifold.
Then there exists a canonical one-form on the cotangentbundle $T^*M$ given by $\lambda_0 : T( T^*M) \to R, (v, \alpha) \mapsto \alpha(\pi_*v)$, with $\pi_*$ the derivative of the natural bundle projection $T^*M \to M$.
It is now possible to pullback this one-form to the tangentbundle using our riemannian metric, so $\lambda = (g^b)^*\lambda_0$. Using this one-form we define a symplectic structure on $TM$ by $\omega = -d\lambda$.

Now let $\phi:R\times  \text{TM} \to \text{TM}, V \mapsto \dot \gamma_V(t) $ be the action generated by the geodesic flow.

My question is, if $\phi$ acts by symplectomorphisms, that is, if $\phi_t^*\omega = \omega$ for all $t\in R$ or is it even exact symplectic, that is, if $\phi_t^*\lambda = \lambda$ for all $t\in R$? Because Im trying to show that this is an hamiltonian action, so that there exists a moment map for this action.

And it would be clear if we have an exact symplectic action.

Edit: To have a well-defined action of $R$, we assume that the manifold is geodesically complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\phi$ is the Hamiltonian flow corresponding to the ``Hamiltonian'' $E:TM\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $E(V) = \frac{1}{2}g(V,V)$. This is pretty standard, and you can read about it in most references on symplectic geometry, for example [Foundations of Mechanics](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/25029/) (in particular, Theorem 3.7.1). The corresponding momentum map of this flow is simply the Hamiltonian $E$ itself (with the canonical identification of $\mathbb{R}^*$ with $\mathbb{R}$).

The flow is not however exact symplectic, and in fact the generator of Hamiltonian flow $X_E\in\mathfrak{X}(TM)$ satisfies $\mathcal{L}_{X_E}\lambda = dL$, where $L$ is the Lagrangian, which equals $E$ in this case. To see this in coordinates, note that
$$
i_{X_E}\lambda = p_i dq^i \left(\dot{q}^i\frac{\partial}{\partial q^i} \right) = p_i\dot{q}^i.
$$
So using Cartan's Magic Formula
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_{X_E} \lambda &= i_{X_E}d\lambda + d(i_{X_E}\lambda) \\
&= -i_{X_E}\omega + d(p_i\dot{q}^i) \\
&= d(p_i\dot{q}^i - E) \\
&= dL.
\end{align*}
For a more geometric treatment, see Foundations of Mechanics, sections 3.5-3.7.